# How to teleport to a specific place but near player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well i'm triying to make a stand (From **jojo's bizarre adventure**) On minecraft, all good, i added the team to erase the collisions, and the Friendly fire. But i got a dismiss, Everytime the command teleport the husk to me, it teleports to my exact coords, but i want it teleports the Husk to 1 block far than me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
execute as <player selector> at @s positioned ~<x offset> ~<y offset> ~<z offset> run tp <husk selector> ~ ~ ~
```

The positioning offset is based on x y and z cords.  For raycasting use the `^` instead of the `~` for the offset.  `^ ^ ^1` is forwards.  `^ ^ ^-1` is backwards.  `^ ^1 ^` is upwards.  `^ ^-1 ^` is downwards.  `^1 ^ ^` is to the left. `^-1 ^ ^` is to the right.

Comment: @Alex_Command your welcome.

Comment: @Alex_Command if this worked for you you should approve it by clicking the grey checkmark as it will close the question and reward the asker with reputation.

Comment: @Penguin It doesn't close the question when an answer is accepted. If the system closes questions when an answer is accepted, what would someone do if they come along with a better answer to the question and want to post it?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 sorry I misused the term "close" I meant it will mark the question as answered. Simple terminology misuse sorry!